# Android WebView url redirection for POST requests

Tags: android, kotlin, post, webview, webclient

There is a payment gateway page url which I should open it in a webview in my application. But the problem is: After filling form inputs on the page in the webview, when click to "Pay" button, the url redirection happens. But the new url is a POST request and I cannot catch it with "shoulOverrideUrlLoading" function of WebClient class, because this function is not called for post requests (this info is mentioned in the documention). But why I need to catch it? Because the new url requires token and app identification static hash code. That's why I want to catch that url and don't load redirection. Instead of that, I use the url catched to manually requesting. What should I do in this case?

```
ui.webView.apply {

            settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true

            isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
            isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true

            scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY

            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?
                ): Boolean {
                    Timber.d("URL: ${request?.url}") //Just for debugging purpose
                    return true
                }

            }

            webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

                override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
                    ui.loading.isVisible = newProgress != 100
                }

                override fun onReceivedTitle(view: WebView?, title: String?) {
                    ui.title.text = title
                }

            }

            setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action === MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && canGoBack()) {
                    goBack()
                    return@OnKeyListener true
                }
                false
            })

        }.loadUrl(args.url)
```